# Delphi ActivexComponentFactory Access Violation on Multi Thread scenario

Tags: multithreading, delphi, activex, access-violation

I have an activex component being created with the threading model "both" on delphi. It works perfectly, until I execute a stress test which create 50 or more threads and starts creating the activex  on each thread. In this scenario after some time of perfect execution, an Access Violation error occurs on the creation of the component, inside AxCmps.TActivexComponentControl.Create, without even reaching my component initialization code. The specific point where the exception occurs is on TWinControl.Create.

Does anyone know if this is a bug, or if I am doing wrong by having multiple threads create an instance of a component with "both" threading model?

Edit: the component isnt visual (means it is an invisible active x)

Edit2: If I wrap the create and free of the component with a critical section, then the problem doesnt occur

Thread code:

```
Coinitialize(nil);
try
for _j := 1 to LOOPS do
begin
  try
    CS.Enter;
    _comp := MyComp.Create(nil);
    CS.Leave;
    try
      CallMethods; //not synchronized
    finally
      CS.Enter;
      _comp.Free;
      CS.Leave;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      LogErrors(E);
  end;
end;
finally
  Couninitialize;
end;
```

Comment: Absolutely no chance at all of running code that calls `TWinControl.Create` on any thread other than the main thread. The VCL threading model forbids that.

Comment: My test calls MyComponent.Create in the execute of the thread

Comment: That's as maybe. You are aware of the VCL threading rules?

Comment: Im aware of the threading models, but Im not aware of these VCL threading rules. Is it wrong to call MyComponent.Create inside a thread other than the main?

Comment: Your code clearly creates a `TWinControl`. You can only do that, and operate on such an object, from the main thread.

Comment: looks to me it is a problem in the rtl or my environment, because serializing the creation and destruction of the component inside the thread code stops the problem

Comment: You are using trial and error. That never works well. It might look like it works. But you need to understand the threading rules.

Comment: Why are you using an object that inherits from a `TWinControl` in your component, when it is a non-visual component?

Comment: Because it had to be a palette component in the past, since I dont implement that part, I may suggest the team a refactoring. I think vcl components cannot be created in a multi threaded environment, as @DavidHeffernan stated

Answer (score 0):

After changing the implementation of my component from TActiveXComponent to TAutoObject and changing the corresponding factory, the access violation stopped occurring in my tests. Instead of using the automatically generated wrapper class TMyComponent.Create, I called CoMyComponent.Create. The only problem is, I cannot hook events through the interface.